# Less than or Equal to on 8004 (machine code)

Tags: machine-code

I'm doing a course and I'm stuck on one of the extension puzzles. It's not marked and doesn't count towards anything.

I'll take you through my thinking. Any (very) subtle hints would be appreciated, I would still like to figure it out myself but I've hit a dead end.

Here's the question.

"Write a 8004 program which works out for any two numbers (values 0..255) whether or not the first number is less than or equal to the second.

The first number will be stored in memory address 14 and the second in address 15.

If the first number is less than or equal to the second, print something non-zero. Otherwise, if it isn't (i.e. it's greater), print 0."

I have 16 bytes to do it in. Well 14 because the last two bytes are taken up by the input numbers.

Here is the full instruction set:

[Full instruction set and Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZyCw.png)

```
Here's my thinking:
1. Swap second number (addr 15) and R0. Second number now loaded into R0.
2. Swap first number and R0. Now First number is in R0, second number is in addr 14. We can keep swapping R0 and addr 14 to switch between testing the First and Second number.
3. Check if First number is 0.
4. If it is 0, the First number is less than or equal to second number -> print Non Zero.
5. If it is not 0, it is unknown, and -1 from the First number for next time.
6. SWAP First Number and Second Number
7. Check if Second number is 0.
8. If it is Not Zero, it's unknown, and -1 from Second number and goto 2. (SWAP again and check the first number..)
9. If it is 0, then the first number is greater than the second number -> print 0.
I'm fairly sure this algorithm works for all cases. BUT it won't FIT! I've tried most everything!
My most recent thinking is along the lines of:
14 15 - second number in R0
14 14 - swap first and second number, use memory address 14 as cache for first/second number
9 x - check if first number is zero, if it is zero, jump to print Not Zero (less than or equal)
2 - minus 1 from first number, so first number -1 will be checked next time
14 14 swap the number so second number is in R0
8 y - check if second number does not equal zero, if it doesn't , -1 and jump to "14 14" (line 2) to swap and check first number again
// don't know how I can -1 from R0 and jump
7 0 if it does equal zero, print 0 (greater than)

Can't minus 1 before checking as if it is 0, then it becomes 255 and messes up the comparison. Need to check for 0 first for both numbers. Need to check the first number first because if the second number -1 = 0 then it is is equal. So if I check second number first, then the first number -1 could equal zero meaning it is greater than or EQUAL to, which is not what we are looking for.

Don't really know where to go from here..
```

Coded up a C program to kind of test of the algorithm -

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL 1
#define GREATER_THAN 0

int main (void) {

    int result;

    int firstNumber = 70;
    int secondNumber = 50;

    // starts here

    jump:

    if (firstNumber == 0) {
        result = LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL;
    } else {
        firstNumber--;

        if (secondNumber != 0) {
            secondNumber--;
            goto jump;
        } else {
            result = GREATER_THAN;
        }
    }

    printf("Result: %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! I got it at last!

The key was to look at how the numbers could be reinterpreted as two byte instructions if jumped to from a different location. There's the hint if anyone else is stuck. Look at your jumps!